# How to rebuild create-react-app from a dockerfile container by passing env_file in docker-compose.yaml

Tags: docker, docker-compose, environment-variables, create-react-app

I will try to be as descriptive as I can but I have an react app built with creat-react-app from this app I build a docker image.

`dockerfile`

```
FROM node:17-alpine

# set working directory
WORKDIR /app

# install app dependencies
#copies package.json and package-lock.json to Docker environment
COPY package.json ./

RUN apk add --no-cache --virtual .gyp python3 make g++ \
    && yarn install \
    && apk del .gyp

# Copies everything over to Docker environment
COPY . ./
RUN yarn build-docker

#install serve package
RUN yarn global add serve

EXPOSE 3000 5000
ENTRYPOINT ["serve", "-s", "build"]
```

Which works fine locally with the `.env` file included in the project. For our production and development we use `docker-compose` and include the `env_file` in our `docker-compose.yaml`

#### docker-compse.yaml sample

```
app:
    container_name: app
    image: {image_source}
    restart: always
    env_file:
      - env/app.env

api:
    container_name: api
    image: {image_source}
    restart: always
    env_file:
      - env/global.env
      - env/db.env
```

The api works fine since it's using `ENTRYPOINT ["npm", "start"]` and reload the `.env` file every time it start, but since the `app` is built before the `docker-compose up -d`,

**Is their a way to rebuild using `yarn build-docker` with `docker-compose` so my new build get the right `.env` file?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found out how to solve the issue.

Instead of building the app within the container I chained both action in `package.json` and simply run the build before the serve.

#### package.json

```json
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "build-docker": "react-scripts --openssl-legacy-provider build",
    "build-start": "react-scripts --openssl-legacy-provider build && serve -s build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
```

`"build-start": "react-scripts --openssl-legacy-provider build && serve -s build"`

And in dockerfile i removed the `yarn build-docker` and changed the entrypoint to `ENTRYPOINT ["npm", "run", "build-start"]`

#### dockerfile

```sh
FROM node:17-alpine

# set working directory
WORKDIR /app

# install app dependencies
#copies package.json and package-lock.json to Docker environment
COPY package.json ./

RUN apk add --no-cache --virtual .gyp python3 make g++ \
    && yarn install \
    && apk del .gyp

# Copies everything over to Docker environment
COPY . ./

##### REMOVED THE FIRST BUILD 
#RUN yarn build-docker 

#install serve package
RUN yarn global add serve

EXPOSE 3000 5000
##### CHANGED THE ENTRYPOINT WITH THE NEW SCRIPT
ENTRYPOINT ["npm", "run", "build-start"]
```

So everytime it goes up with docker-compose the `.env` is used during the build.

Hope this could help someone!